# Spring-WS : Soap fault not identified as Fault

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws

I am using Spring-WS, and I am getting a SOAP Fault with error code 500 when calling the web service via marshalSendAndReceive from the webServiceTemplate. Unfortunately, the response is not being recognized as a SOAP fault (it is throwing a WebServiceTransportException). In theory, when there is an error response, WebServiceTemplate throws a WebServiceTransportException if the error code is different to 2xx, **unless** the http error is 500 and the content is a soap fault. Here is an example from the response I get:

```
    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
Content-Length: 887[\r][\n]"
Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"

2015-07-01 10:38:22,873 DEBUG [o.s.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] Received error for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.example.com/schema/front}use]
2015-07-01 10:38:22,874 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,874 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,874 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,874 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "    <SOAP-ENV:Body>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "            <faultstring>Request service/operation version not supported</faultstring>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "            <faultactor>Server</faultactor>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "            <detail>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "                <ns0:serviceException xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/facade/interface/v1_1">[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "                    <ns1:message xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/common/v1_3">InternalCode01</ns1:messageId>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "                    <ns1:text xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/common/v2_1">Request service/operation version not supported</ns1:text>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "                </ns0:serviceException>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "            </detail>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "    </SOAP-ENV:Body>[\n]"
2015-07-01 10:38:22,875 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] << "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

Does anyone know why is it happening? Is there a way to just treat it as the SOAP fault it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged a little bit into the *hasFault* method from AbstractHttpSenderConnection (the one that will be called to decide if the error is a soap fault or not), and I see the next code for that method:

```
/*
 * Faults
 */

public final boolean hasFault() throws IOException {
    return HttpTransportConstants.STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR == getResponseCode() && isXmlResponse();
}

/** Determine whether the response is a XML message. */
private boolean isXmlResponse() throws IOException {
    Iterator<String> iterator = getResponseHeaders(HttpTransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String contentType = iterator.next().toLowerCase();
        return contentType.indexOf("xml") != -1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That means, that there has to be an http header with ContentType = xml, which the web service I am calling is not setting. I have to research now how to set that header in the responses before the error is evaluated in the web service template.

Answer (score 2):

The [`checkConnectionForFault`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#setCheckConnectionForFault(boolean)) property in `WebServiceTemplate` should allow you to work around this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is being set to true (I have extended this class to be able to insert logs, and it is being set to true). Problem is the response doesn't send the HTTP header ContentType=xml .

Comment: No, you should set this to false to skip the code that checks the content type.